# Join 3 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 *MySQL* tables.
I am storing bookings in the `bookings` table & the event dates and times in separate MySQL tables.

I want to have a MySQL query to list available times for a specific date.

So if I enter date of value `1` it'll show no times available but if I enter `2` it'll output `1 | 9:00`.

```
INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `email`, `date_requested`, `time_requested`) VALUES
(1, 'test@test.com',    '1',    '1'),
(2, 'test2@test.com',   '1',    '2'),
(3, 'test3@test.com',   '2',    '2');

INSERT INTO `bookings_dates` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '2022-11-05'),
(2, '2022-11-06'),
(3, '2022-11-07');

INSERT INTO `bookings_times` (`id`, `time`) VALUES
(1, '9:00'),
(2, '9:15');
```

Comment: I can't get what you are trying to achieve. In your sample you have 2 bookings at date_requestd=1 in two different times. I think entering a  value of (1) for date will give you 2 records.

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for dates and times, instead of a single table with date and time? And you should then use a single `DATETIME` value, not separate `date` and `time` columns

Comment: Doesn't a booking need both a start and end date/time?

Comment: @Ehab Sorry, I should explain. They are 2 bookings at 2 different times.

Comment: @Barmar That's a really good point. I may redesign the table structure.

Comment: Although that redesign might make this particular query harder.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, that's my concern. I thought by separating the date/times from the bookings, it would be easier to run queries. Ultimately I was just looking to have a list of available time slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT IN` condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings_times
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT time_requested
    FROM bookings
    WHERE date_requested = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM bookings_dates 
        WHERE date = '2022-11-05'
    )
)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6d3da/4)

Answer (score -1):

In order to get times for a given day (1) you can use the following query :

```
SELECT 
  t.`id`, t.`time`
FROM 
  bookings_times AS t
  INNER JOIN bookings AS b ON b.time_requested = t.id
WHERE
  b.date_requested = 1
```

## Edit1:

In order to get times not in use for a given day (1) you can use the following query :

```
SELECT 
  t.`id`, t.`time`
FROM 
  bookings_times AS t
  LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON b.time_requested = t.id AND (b.date_requested = 1)
WHERE
  IsNull(b.time_requested)
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what he wants. He wants the times that are NOT in use on a day.